# I am getting runtime error "2147188160 (80048240)" saying- "Rows (unknown member): Integer out of range.18 is not in the valid range of 1 to 17"

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have an excel file with survey data for employees with a column dedicated for 'comments received'. I use a vba macro tool to prepare ppt reports for each survey participants which consists of various insights and at last copies the 'comments received' and pastes it on the ppt report.

The problem is when the number of survey input for a participant exceeds 17, it throws an error while on the 'comment received' slide. I am unable to decode the why as I am not an expert at it. Would appreciate your help if you can help in fixing this. Thanks in advance! See the code (it it till a certain section). I have highlighted the error line (at the end of the code) with comments.

```
    Sub MainMacro(ByVal List_Generate As Integer) ' Populates list with number of assessments per assessed
    Dim wbData As Workbook, wsIn As Worksheet
    Dim strIn As String, strInSelf As String, minA As Integer, aA As Integer, nA As Long
    Dim rmax As Long, cmax As Integer, r As Long, Same As Boolean
    Dim strFirst As String, strLast As String, strECode As String, strOpen As String
    Dim s As Integer
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' set me variables
    Set wbTool = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsRun = wbTool.Worksheets("Macro")
    Set wsList = wbTool.Worksheets("List")
    Set wsStatements = wbTool.Worksheets("Statements")
     
    ' get settings
    strTempl = wsRun.Cells(6, 2)
    strIn = wsRun.Cells(10, 2)
    boSelf = wsRun.Cells(12, 2)
    strInSelf = wsRun.Cells(15, 2)
    strOutPath = wsRun.Cells(19, 2)
    minA = wsRun.Cells(22, 2)
    strDate = wsRun.Cells(22, 5)

    If List_Generate = 1 Then
      ' Delete old list if existing
      rmax = wsList.Cells(wsList.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      If rmax > 3 Then
        wsList.Activate
        wsList.Range(wsList.Cells(4, 1), wsList.Cells(rmax, 5)).Select
        Selection.Delete
      End If
    End If
     ReDim arrS(1 To 2, 1 To 32)
    ReDim arrSSStre(1 To 5, 1 To 32)
    ReDim arrSSEnth(1 To 5, 1 To 32)
    If List_Generate = 2 Then
      For s = 1 To 32
        arrS(1, s) = wsStatements.Cells(s + 2, 2)
        If boSelf = 1 Then
          arrSSStre(1, s) = wsStatements.Cells(s + 2, 4)
          arrSSStre(2, s) = wsStatements.Cells(s + 2, 5)
          arrSSStre(3, s) = wsStatements.Cells(s + 2, 6)
          arrSSEnth(1, s) = wsStatements.Cells(s + 2, 4)
          arrSSEnth(2, s) = wsStatements.Cells(s + 2, 5)
          arrSSEnth(3, s) = wsStatements.Cells(s + 2, 6)
        End If
      Next
      
    End If

    ' Open Data-Files
    On Error GoTo err_DatFile
    Set wbData = Application.Workbooks.Open(strIn)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set wsIn = wbData.Sheets(1)
    
    If boSelf = 1 And List_Generate = 2 Then
        On Error GoTo err_DatSelfFile
        Set wbDataSelf = Application.Workbooks.Open(strInSelf)
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set wsInSelf = wbDataSelf.Sheets(1)
    End If

     With wsIn
        ' Sort by Assessed
        rmax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        cmax = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Activate
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(rmax, cmax)).Select
        
        Selection.Sort Key1:=.Range("p2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
        Selection.Sort Key1:=.Range("o2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Key2:=.Range("m2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
            Key3:=.Range("n2"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

     ' Loop over all assessments
        nA = 0
        
        For r = 3 To rmax
            Same = False
            
           If Trim(.Cells(r, 16)) = Trim(.Cells(r - 1, 16)) And _
              Trim(.Cells(r, 15)) = Trim(.Cells(r - 1, 15)) And _
              Trim(.Cells(r, 14)) = Trim(.Cells(r - 1, 14)) And _
              Trim(.Cells(r, 13)) = Trim(.Cells(r - 1, 13)) Then Same = True
               
            If Same = False Then
                If r > 3 Then
                  If List_Generate = 1 Then Call PasteA(strFirst, strLast, strECode, strOpen, aA, nA)
              

    If List_Generate = 2 And aA >= minA Then Call MakeReport(strFirst, strLast, strECode, aA, nA)
                End If
                nA = nA + 1
                strLast = Trim(.Cells(r, 13))
                strFirst = Trim(.Cells(r, 14))
                strECode = Trim(.Cells(r, 15))
                strOpen = Trim(.Cells(r, 16))
                aA = 1
                If List_Generate = 2 Then
                  For s = 1 To 32
                    arrS(2, s) = 0
                  Next
                  For s = 1 To 32
                    If .Cells(r, 16 + s) = 1 Then arrS(2, s) = arrS(2, s) + 1
                  Next
                  Set clsCommA = New Collection
                  clsCommA.Add .Cells(r, 49)
                End If
            Else
                If List_Generate = 2 Then
                  For s = 1 To 32
                    If .Cells(r, 16 + s) = 1 Then arrS(2, s) = arrS(2, s) + 1
                  Next
                  clsCommA.Add .Cells(r, 49)
                End If
                aA = aA + 1
            End If
        Next
        If List_Generate = 1 Then Call PasteA(strFirst, strLast, strECode, strOpen, aA, nA)
        If List_Generate = 2 And aA >= minA Then Call MakeReport(strFirst, strLast, strECode, aA, nA)
        
    End With

    bData.Close
    If boSelf = 1 And List_Generate = 2 Then wbDataSelf.Close
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    MsgBox ("Ready")
    
    Exit Sub
    
    err_DatFile:
        MsgBox ("Data File '" & strIn & "' couldn't be opened")
        Exit Sub
    
    err_DatSelfFile:
        MsgBox ("Data File '" & strInSelf & "' couldn't be opened")
        Exit Sub
    
    End Sub

  

    Sub PasteA(ByVal strFirst As String, ByVal strLast As String, ByVal strECode As String, ByVal 
       strOpen As String, ByVal aA As Integer, ByVal nA As Long)
      wsList.Cells(nA + 3, 1) = strLast
      wsList.Cells(nA + 3, 2) = strFirst
      wsList.Cells(nA + 3, 3) = strECode
      wsList.Cells(nA + 3, 4) = strOpen
      wsList.Cells(nA + 3, 5) = aA
     End Sub

    Sub MakeReport(ByVal strFirst As String, ByVal strLast As String, ByVal strECode As String, ByVal aA As Integer, ByVal nA As Long)
    Dim strOutfile As String, Sl As PowerPoint.Slide, sh As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim strText As String
    Dim s As Integer, saa As Integer, nm As Integer, nmr As Integer, nmc As Integer
    Dim rSelf As Long, rngSelf As Range, AvgStre As Double, StdStre As Double, AvgEnth As Double, StdEnth As Double, tr As Integer, tc As Integer
    Dim myChart As PowerPoint.Chart
    Dim myChartData As PowerPoint.ChartData
    Dim myWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim myWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strSource As String

    
    ' Number of mentioned statements
    Call SortArr(arrS(), 2, "d")
    s = 1
    nm = 32
    Do
      saa = arrS(2, s)
      If saa = 0 Then
        nm = s
      End If
      s = s + 1
    Loop Until saa = 0 Or s = 33
    
    ' Open Slide Template and save under new name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        Err.Clear
    End If
    PPApp.Activate
    Set PPress = PPApp.Presentations
    On Error GoTo PPError
    Set PPres = PPress.Item(strTempl)
    On Error GoTo 0
    strOutfile = strOutPath & "\Emerging Strengths Assessment " & strFirst & " " & strLast & ".pptx"
    
    ' 

    Update Title Slide
        Set Sl = PPres.Slides(1)
        With Sl
            .Shapes("Subtitle 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strDate
            .Shapes("TextBox 9").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strFirst & " " & strLast
        End With
    
   

     ' Paste Data
        Set Sl = PPres.Slides(3)
            
        With Sl
          Set sh = .Shapes("TextBox 11")
          strText = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
          If Right(strFirst, 1) = "s" Then
    

    strText = Replace(strText, "____’s", strFirst & "’")
      Else
        strText = Replace(strText, "____’s", strFirst & "’s")
      End If
      sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strText
      
 

     Set sh = .Shapes("TextBox 23")
      strText = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
      strText = Replace(strText, "10", aA)
      strText = Replace(strText, "2/27/14", strDate)
     sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strText
      
      Set sh = .Shapes("Chart 2")
      Set myChart = sh.Chart
      Set myChartData = myChart.ChartData
      myChartData.Activate
      Set myWorkBook = myChartData.Workbook
      Set myWorkSheet = myWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
      With myWorkSheet
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(33, 2)).Clear
        .Activate
        .ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("A1:B" & nm)
                For s = 1 To nm - 1
                    .Cells(s + 1, 1) = arrS(1, s)
                    .Cells(s + 1, 2) = arrS(2, s)
                Next
      End With
      myWorkBook.Close
      myChartData.Activate
      strSource = "='Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$" & nm
      myChart.SetSourceData Source:=strSource
      Set myWorkBook = Nothing
      Set myChartData = Nothing     
    End With

 Update Comments Slide
    Set Sl = PPres.Slides(4)
    Set sh = Sl.Shapes("TextBox 7")
    strText = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    strText = Replace(strText, "____", strFirst)
    sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strText  
    Set sh = Sl.Shapes("Table Placeholder 3")
    For s = 1 To aA
        sh.Table.Rows(s + 1).Cells(1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(clsCommA.Item(s)) 'this is error line
    Next
    If aA < 16 Then
        For s = 16 To aA + 1 Step -1
            sh.Table.Rows(s + 1).Delete
     Next
    End If
    Set clsCommA = Nothing
```

Comment: How many rows are there in the table on slide 4?

Comment: @PeterT desirably there shouldn't be any limit to it. Example- an employee can receive 20 comments or more and we want all of them in slide 4. But incase of the macro, if the number of comments exceeds 17, it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly have as many comments as you want, but you have to manage the number of rows for table on the slide. If you exceed the existing number of rows, you have to add a new row. The example below shows how you can check:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim slyde As Slide
    Set slyde = Presentations(1).Slides(1)
    
    Dim comments As Shape
    Set comments = slyde.Shapes("Table 4")
    
    Dim i As Long
    '--- artificially go past the existing number of rows
    For i = 1 To comments.Table.Rows.Count + 5
        If i > comments.Table.Rows.Count Then
            comments.Table.Rows.Add
        End If
        comments.Table.Rows(i).Cells(1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "row " & i
    Next i
End Sub
```